# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, react-redux, reactjs, react-router-redux

This is quite confusing for me but I'm clearly missing something.

To get up to speed, here is my current react-router setup

I've already done `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}` within the layout of the app component, and other routes are working fine passing the props down via `{...this.props}`. Just not on the children components of the IndexRoute component.

```
render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Week} />
        <Route path='/cook-book' component={Cookbook} />
        <Route path='/cook-book/:recipe' name='Recipe' component={Recipe} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

And the error occurs within the `Week` component which is below:

```
render () {
    return (
      <div className='week__weekly-container'>
        <h1>This is the weekly container</h1>
        <Day title='Monday' {...this.props} />
        <Day title='Tuesday' {...this.props} />
        <Day title='Wednesday' {...this.props} />
        <Day title='Thursday' {...this.props} />
        <Day title='Friday' {...this.props} />
        <Day title='Saturday' {...this.props} />
        <Day title='Sunday' {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

React throws an error when I do this (but only on this component): `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys...`

As I've done it `Cookbook` & `Recipe` components: (See below).

I'm wondering if it's something to do with the `Week` Component being the IndexRoute? But other than that I'm completely lost.

Cookbook Component which works fine...:

```
render () {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>Cookbook Recipes</h1>
        <Recipes {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Recipe component uses the same thing...

```
<RecipeWeekDay name='Monday' mealName={meal.name} mealSlug={meal.slug} {...this.props} />
```

Comment: What's in the `this.props`?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that within my `Day` component, I was trying to render what I thought was a string but was ultimately a Javascript object which was throwing the error.

```
class Day extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div className='week__single-week'>
        <h4 className='week__title text-center'>{this.props.title}</h4>
        <p>{this.props.meals}</p> //- This was an array of objects and not a string.
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Day
```